# Adding fields to the "Add New User" screen in the dashboard

Tags: functions, wp-admin, users, user-meta, user-registration

I'd like to add the field "Company Name" to the add new user page in the admin panel. I've done quite a bit of searching and have been unable to find details on how to do this. I can easily add info to the profile page and registration with..

```
   function my_custom_userfields( $contactmethods ) {
    //Adds customer contact details
    $contactmethods['company_name'] = 'Company Name';
    return $contactmethods;
   }
   add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_custom_userfields',10,1);
```

But no dice on anything else.

Comment: You can use the [ACF ( Advanced Custom Fields ) plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you'll have to manually change the user-new.php page. It's not the correct way to handle it but if you're in desperate need this is how it's done.

I added

```
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row"><label for="company_name"><?php _e('Company Name') ?> </label></th>
    <td><input name="company_name" type="text" id="company_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($new_user_companyname); ?>" /></td>
</tr>
```

I also added the information to functions.php

```
   function my_custom_userfields( $contactmethods ) {
    $contactmethods['company_name']             = 'Company Name';
    return $contactmethods;
   }
   add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_custom_userfields',10,1);
```

Comment: This is the working answer.

Answer (score 26):

[`user_new_form`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/user_new_form) is the hook that can do the magic here.

```
function custom_user_profile_fields($user){
  ?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="company">Company Name</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="company" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'company', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="company" /><br />
                <span class="description">Where are you?</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( "user_new_form", "custom_user_profile_fields" );

function save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id){
    # again do this only if you can
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
        return false;

    # save my custom field
    update_usermeta($user_id, 'company', $_POST['company']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('profile_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
```

For more details visit my blog post: http://scriptbaker.com/adding-custom-fields-to-wordpress-user-profile-and-add-new-user-page/

Answer (score 13):

I had the same need and created the following hack:

```
<?php
function hack_add_custom_user_profile_fields(){
    global $pagenow;

    # do this only in page user-new.php
    if($pagenow !== 'user-new.php')
        return;

    # do this only if you can
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
        return false;

?>
<table id="table_my_custom_field" style="display:none;">
<!-- My Custom Code { -->
    <tr>
        <th><label for="my_custom_field">My Custom Field</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="my_custom_field" id="my_custom_field" /></td>
    </tr>
<!-- } -->
</table>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    //Move my HTML code below user's role
    $('#table_my_custom_field tr').insertAfter($('#role').parentsUntil('tr').parent());
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('admin_footer_text', 'hack_add_custom_user_profile_fields');


function save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id){
    # again do this only if you can
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
        return false;

    # save my custom field
    update_usermeta($user_id, 'my_custom_field', $_POST['my_custom_field']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
```

Comment: Now we are waiting for your explanation.

Comment: I saw the source code in file user-new.php e don't have a action hook like "add_user_profile" so I simulate this with the action "admin_footer_text" and filter by $pagenow == "user-new.php".

Now I commented the hack to explain the code.

Comment: Why you do not use `user_new_form` action?

Comment: @SazzadTusharKhan tx for the pointer

Answer (score 4):

You need to do 2 things.

1. Register fields
2. Save fields

***Note:* Below example works only for `administrator` user role.**

---

#### 1. Register fields

For **Add New User** use action `user_new_form`

For **User Profile** use actions `show_user_profile`, `edit_user_profile`

**Register fields Snippet:**

```
/**
 * Add fields to user profile screen, add new user screen
 */
if( !function_exists('m_register_profile_fields') ) {

    //  This action for 'Add New User' screen
    add_action( 'user_new_form', 'm_register_profile_fields' );

    //  This actions for 'User Profile' screen
    add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'm_register_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'm_register_profile_fields' );

    function m_register_profile_fields( $user ) {

        if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator', $user_id ) )
            return false;

        ?>

        <h3>Client Portal</h3>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="dropdown">Portal Category</label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="portal_cat" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'portal_cat', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="portal_cat" /><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php }
}
```

---

#### 2. Save fields

For **Add New User** use action `user_register`

For **User Profile** use actions `personal_options_update`, `edit_user_profile_update`

**Save fields Snippet:**

```
/**
 *  Save portal category field to user profile page, add new profile page etc
 */
if( !function_exists('m_register_profile_fields') ) {

    //  This action for 'Add New User' screen
    add_action( 'user_register', 'cp_save_profile_fields' );

    //  This actions for 'User Profile' screen
    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'cp_save_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'cp_save_profile_fields' );

    function cp_save_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

        if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator', $user_id ) )
            return false;

        update_usermeta( $user_id, 'portal_cat', $_POST['portal_cat'] );
    }
}
```

### Complete Code Snippet:

```
/**
 * Add fields to user profile screen, add new user screen
 */
if( !function_exists('m_register_profile_fields') ) {

    //  This action for 'Add New User' screen
    add_action( 'user_new_form', 'm_register_profile_fields' );

    //  This actions for 'User Profile' screen
    add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'm_register_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'm_register_profile_fields' );

    function m_register_profile_fields( $user ) {

        if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator', $user_id ) )
            return false;

        ?>

        <h3>Client Portal</h3>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="dropdown">Portal Category</label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="portal_cat" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'portal_cat', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="portal_cat" /><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php }
}


/**
 *  Save portal category field to user profile page, add new profile page etc
 */
if( !function_exists('m_register_profile_fields') ) {

    //  This action for 'Add New User' screen
    add_action( 'user_register', 'cp_save_profile_fields' );

    //  This actions for 'User Profile' screen
    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'cp_save_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'cp_save_profile_fields' );

    function cp_save_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

        if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator', $user_id ) )
            return false;

        update_usermeta( $user_id, 'portal_cat', $_POST['portal_cat'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, This is not getting saved in user_meta

Comment: Instead of `if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator', $user_id ) )` use `if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )`. The function current_user_can() parametes are now updated - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

Answer (score 3):

The hooks are important, no matter how we sorted form fields inside the function. Follow my inline comments. As of WordPress 4.2.2 we have plenty of hooks now:

```
<?php
/**
 * Declaring the form fields
 */
function wpse23813_show_my_fields( $user ) {
   $fetched_field = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'my_field', true ); ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
       <th scope="row"><label for="my-field"><?php _e('Field Name') ?> </label></th>
       <td><input name="my_field" type="text" id="my-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr($fetched_field); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'wpse23813_show_my_fields' ); //show in my profile.php page
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'wpse23813_show_my_fields' ); //show in my profile.php page

//add_action( 'user_new_form_tag', 'wpse23813_show_my_fields' ); //to add the fields before the user-new.php form
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'wpse23813_show_my_fields' ); //to add the fields after the user-new.php form

/**
 * Saving my form fields
 */
function wpse23813_save_my_form_fields( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_field', $_POST['my_field'] );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'wpse23813_save_my_form_fields' ); //for profile page update
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'wpse23813_save_my_form_fields' ); //for profile page update

add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse23813_save_my_form_fields' ); //for user-new.php page new user addition
```

Answer (score 1):

`user_contactmethods` filter hook does not get called at the `user-new.php` page so that wont work and sadly if you take a [look at the source](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/user-new.php) you will see that there is no hook that can be used to add extra fields to the add new user form.

So this can only be done by either modifying core files (BIG NO NO) or adding the fields using JavaScript or jQuery and catching the fields.

or you can create a [Ticket at the Trac](http://codex.wordpress.org/Reporting_Bugs)

Comment: Unfortunately, in order to get it to work, temporarily, I was forced to modify user-new.php. This is a no no. But hopefully it's temporary.

Answer (score 1):

I workaround is available by using the `user_new_form_tag` which resides inside the `user-new.php` page's form starting tag. It's in the end so if you output HTML after that you just need to begin the output with `>` and remove the last outputted `>` of your own code. As in:

```
function add_new_field_to_useradd()
{
    echo "><div>"; // Note the first '>' here. We wrap our own output to a 'div' element.

    // Your wanted output code should be here here.

    echo "</div"; // Note the missing '>' here.
}

add_action( "user_new_form_tag", "add_new_field_to_useradd" );
```

The `user_new_form_tag` is situated in `user-new.php` around line 303 (in WP3.5.1 at least):

```
...
<p><?php _e('Create a brand new user and add it to this site.'); ?></p>
<form action="" method="post" name="createuser" id="createuser" class="validate"<?php do_action('user_new_form_tag');?>>
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="createuser" />
...
```

Of course the downside here is that all your custom field must appear first in the form, before the fields declared in WP core.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will display "Biographical Info" in "Add User" form

```
function display_bio_field() {
  echo "The field html";
}
add_action('user_new_form', 'display_bio_field');
```

Comment: A code-only answer is a bad answer. Try linking related Codex article and explaining the code here.

Answer (score 0):

This won't do it for the add new user page, but if you want to make it happen in the "Your Profile" page (where users can edit their profile), then you can try this in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="companyname">Company Name</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'companyname', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description">Where are you?</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }
```